# "Error creating bean with name" Couchbase + Spring

Tags: java, spring, couchbase, nosql

I'm trying to figure out how to get Spring to work with Couchbase but for some reason I'm getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bookRepo': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'couchbaseTemplate' while setting bean property 'couchbaseOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'couchbaseTemplate': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'couchbaseBucket' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'couchbaseBucket': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
```

The connection is fine but for some reason the beans cannot be created.

Here's my `spring-couchbase-integration.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:couchbase="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/couchbase"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/couchbase
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/couchbase/spring-couchbase.xsd">

    <couchbase:cluster>
        <couchbase:node>127.0.0.1</couchbase:node>
    </couchbase:cluster>

    <!-- This is needed to probe the server for N1QL support -->
    <!-- Can be either cluster credentials or a bucket credentials -->
    <couchbase:clusterInfo login="login"
        password="password" />

    <beans:bean id="couchbaseEnv"
        class="com.couchbase.client.java.env.DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment"
        factory-method="create" />
    <beans:bean id="myCustomTranslationService"
        class="org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.translation.JacksonTranslationService" />

    <couchbase:indexManager />

    <couchbase:repositories base-package="com.jcg.examples.repo" />

    <couchbase:template translation-service-ref="myCustomTranslationService" />

    <couchbase:bucket bucketName="JavaCodeGeeks"
        bucketPassword="password.1" />
</beans:beans>
```

Here's the repository:

```
package com.jcg.examples.repo;

...

@Repository
public interface BookRepo extends CouchbaseRepository<Book, Long> {

    @Query(value = "select * from JavaCodeGeeks")
    public List<Book> getBooksByContainedWord(String containedString);
}
```

The document:

```
package com.jcg.examples.entity;

...

@Document(expiry = 0)
public class Book {

    @Id
    private long bookId;

    public long getBookId() {
        return bookId;
    }

    public void setBookId(long bookId) {
            this.bookId = bookId;
    }

}
```

And a here's how I'm testing it:

```
package com.jcg.examples;

...

public class ApplicationTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new ClassPathResource("spring-couchbase-integration.xml").getPath());
    }
}
```

The example is taken from [this website](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/data/spring-data-couchbase-example/). I've managed to fix the connection issues since I'm not actually using `localhost` but I haven't been able to figure this one out.

**EDIT**: The problem was fixed [by configuring the Docker container properly](https://hub.docker.com/r/couchbase/server/) thus fixing the connection issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message indicates that the SDK couldn't connect to the cluster quickly enough. The default timeout is 5 seconds.

Is Couchbase Server up and running on `localhost`? If you are using another IP in your actual config, can the client machine ping to it? With what latency?

You can try setting a higher timeout (in milliseconds):

```
<couchbase:env id="couchbaseEnv" connectTimeout="10000" />
```

Comment: +1 this seems like a connection issue. I set up a couchbase server locally and the code runs just fine. Currently, I am getting a connection timed out: /<server-ip>:8092 when trying to add a document.

Comment: 8092 is the port for views (which Spring Data Couchbase relies heavily on). Could there be a firewall issue? The Couchbase SDK talks to the cluster nodes directly, on several ports especially the 8091-8094 range...

Comment: I'll accept this as an answer since this pointed me in the right direction. The problem was with the ports and how the docker container was configured. Thank you!